# Drawing a 7-node polygon

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

I am trying to draw 7 nodes in the shape of a heptagon, I have found how to draw the heptagon, but I dont how how to label each node 1-7 and then how to draw edges between the nodes.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[fill=white, thick, node distance = 2cm, auto,rotate=90,transform shape]
\foreach \a in {51.43,102.86,...,361} {%\a is the angle variable
\draw[fill] (\a:3cm) circle (10pt); % 2cm is the radius; 10pt is the radius of the small bullet
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use an heptagonal `regular polygon` on background, and draw labels on its corners.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=7, minimum size=3cm] (a) {};
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,7}
    \node[circle, draw, fill=white] at (a.corner \i) {\i};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to remove the edges and replace them with the edges I have in the picture below?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you looking for the following diagram:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.style = {circle, draw, fill=white, minimum size=1.5em},
       arr/.style = {-Stealth, shorten >=1pt}
                        ]
%%%% variable data
\def\numpoly{7}%number of nodes
\def\startangle{90}%angle of the first node
\def\pradius{32mm}
%------- calculations positions angles
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle-360/\numpoly)}%
    \let\nextangle=\pgfmathresult
\pgfmathparse{int(\startangle-7*360/\numpoly)}%
    \let\endangle=\pgfmathresult
%--- polygon nodes
    \foreach \i [count=\ii from 0,  count=\k] in {\startangle,\nextangle,...,\endangle}
{
\path (\i:\pradius) node (p\ii) {\k};
}
%--- nodes interconnections
\foreach \i in {0,...,6}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ii}{int(Mod(\i+1,\numpoly))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ij}{int(Mod(\i+2,\numpoly))}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ik}{int(Mod(\i+4,\numpoly))}
\draw[arr] (p\i) -- (p\ii);
\draw[arr] (p\i) -- (p\ij);
\draw[arr] (p\i) -- (p\ik);
}
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note*:
MWE above enable do draw arbitrary (regular) polygon. You only need to select number of nodes, defined in `\def\numpoly{...}`.